# How to correctly install package from a local folder directory?

Tags: r

I create an R Package project and install it using the following code.

```
install.packages("f:/Desktop/function/", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

However, when I try to attach the package with `library(function)`, I got

```
Error: unexpected ')' in "library(function)"
```

How should I correctly install a custom package?

Comment: `function` is a key command in `R` that should not be used to create custom objects. It's messing names. I recommend first to change the name of the package and see if the problem persists

Comment: @linog solved my issue!

Comment: Cool ! I put it as an answer then, you can accept it ([guidelines here if needed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function` is a key command in `R` that should not be used to create custom objects. It's messing names.

I recommend to change the name of the package.